# State-of-the-art in smoothing splines

Tags: smoothing, splines, linear-algebra

What is the state-of-the-art in the efficient computation of smoothing splines?

The algorithm I see mentioned most often is that of [Reinsch](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/class/cap5416fa10/resources/Reinsch_1967.pdf), dating back to 1967. As I understand it, the most expensive part is performing a Cholesky decomposition. What other algorithms for smoothing splines have there been since then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit more modern than what you quote is de Boor, C. (1978) *A Practical Guide to Splines*, Springer Verlag.  An efficient algorithm for smoothing splines is given by Hutchinson, M.F. and de Hoog, F.R. (1985) Smoothing Noisy Data with Spline Functions, *Numerische Mathematik*, 47, p. 99-106 (see also Hutchinson, M.F. (1986) Cubic Spline Data Smoother, *Transactions on Mathematical Software*, vol. 12, 150-153;
you will find the FORTRAN source of the algortihm in http://calgo.acm.org).

Note also that the Kalman filter can be a good tool to fit some types of splines; see for instance an answer I gave sometime ago on [Kalman filter vs. smoothing splines](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15070/kalman-filter-vs-smoothing-splines). You will find much relevant information if you search here in CrossValidated using "splines" as a tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

As far as I can tell, the algorithm in _A Practical Guide to Splines_ is the same as the one given by Reinsch.

I haven't yet looked at your other reference.

Regarding Kalman filters, I believe they would require additional structure, such as knowledge about transitions between data points.