# Calculus with quadratic B-spline

Tags: splines, calculus

After fitting a quadratic B-spline in R with the cobs package :

```
Rbs <- cobs(x,y, constraint= "decrease", pointwise = con)
```

I would like to do some calculus on the fitted splines, like calculating the derivative, or the average value on an interval (which is linked to its integral).

For exemple I got :

```
> Rbs$knots
[1]   1  40 100
> Rbs$coef
[1] 1 2 3 5
> Rbs$degree
[1] 2
```

How one would go to build a B-spline approximated function with knots and coefficients ? (note that I looked at https://github.com/cran/cobs/blob/master/R/splines.R for the predict function but couldn't find exactly where it is build and how). For derivative and integral, is there any easy way to find their expression based on those knots and coefficients, to express them in terms of knots and coefficients ?

Comment: My post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/429853/919, including the code at the end, shows how to compute spline derivatives numerically for *any* spline.  It requires only that you supply a `predict` function to compute spline values.

Comment: It seems to be a numerical approximation. It's not that it shouldn't work (approximating the integral with rectangles should work too). But I feel like (1) exact solutions for derivative / integral based on knots and coefficients seems achievable, (2) exact solutions may avoid hard-to-spot approximation problems, (3) it may even help me understand how B-splines work and (4) help me find further code optimisation if I need to perform more complex calculations / on multiples splines.

Comment: Yes, exact expressions are achievable.  For most applications, though, it's not worth the effort to work them out.  The risk with an exact solution is that you don't derive exactly the right expression or there's a bug in your code.  As far as code optimization goes, for a $k^\text{th}$ order derivative you need $k+1$ spline evaluations, so you're talking about a factor of only $2$ or $3,$ which is scarcely worth considering. The strongest case for working out the algebraic solution is for theoretical analysis, but since you don't propose a specific application there's nothing to say there.

Comment: I can understand your point in the general case of fitting a handfull of splines. But in my case the splines may be used in some intensive calculations - a factor 2 or 3 would be more than welcome...

Comment: should I just ask how B-spline are built from knot and coefficients ?