# 2nd derivative of spline

Tags: r, splines, derivative

This question has some similarities to a previous related question.
[How can I fit a spline to data that contains values and 1st/2nd derivatives?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/428558/how-can-i-fit-a-spline-to-data-that-contains-values-and-1st-2nd-derivatives)

I went through the suggestions mentioned in that post, no issues with the theory but I am not sure how to implement that in R. So basically I am asking a similar question and wondering if there are any simple solutions to computing the 2nd derivative of a cubic spline using this example below.

```
#loading the Splines Packages
require(splines) 

#ISLR contains the Dataset
require(ISLR)
attach(Wage) #attaching Wage dataset

agelims <- range(age)

#Generating Test Data
age.grid <- seq(from=agelims[1], to = agelims[2])


This is a Cubic Spline with 3 Knots (cutpoints)

#3 cutpoints at ages 25 ,50 ,60
bs(age, knots = c(25,40,60))
```

How do I compute the second derivative of cubic spline function `bs` ? Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The `R` code I posted in your link computes numerical derivatives.  That makes it universally applicable (it doesn't care what kind of spline is used) and would appear to answer your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe one can achieve this with the `splines2` package in R, which essentially takes the original `splines` package and adds some additional functionality to it (this package was first developed in 2016, so you can read more about it in the developer's 2021 paper [here](https://jds-online.org/journal/JDS/article/1243/info) and a vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splines2/vignettes/splines2-intro.html)). There are two specific functions for `bs` splines which calculate the integrals and derivatives. Since you ask specifically for the derivatives, I show that here by first loading the packages and creating the data.

```
#### Load Library ####
library(splines) # original package 
library(splines2) # "supplementary" package

#### Set Knots and Data Points ####
x <- seq(0, 1, 0.01)
knots <- c(0.3, 0.5, 0.6)
```

Then we can get the derivatives with the `dbs` function, which has many of the same arguments as `bs` but includes which order of derivatives to calculate (annotated below). You then simply plot the object saved in R:

```
#### Plot First Order Derivatives ####
dbsMat <- dbs(
  x,
  knots = knots,
  degree = 3,
  intercept = TRUE, 
  derivs = 1 # only difference here his specifying derivative
)

plot(
  dbsMat,
  main="First Order Derivatives"
)
```

Shown here:

[image]

To get the second-order derivatives, you just have the specify it with the same `derivs` argument:

```
#### Plot Second Order Derivatives ####
dbsMat2 <- dbs(
  x,
  knots = knots,
  degree = 3,
  intercept = TRUE, 
  derivs = 2 # change this to f''(x)
)

plot(
  dbsMat2,
  main="Second Order Derivatives"
)
```

Shown here:

[image]

For your own example data, it would look like this:

```
#### ISLR Example: Get Derivatives ####
d1 <- dbs(age, knots = c(25,40,60), derivs = 1)
d2 <- dbs(age, knots = c(25,40,60), derivs = 2)

#### Plot ####
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(d1,
     main="First Order Derivatives")
plot(d2,
     main="Second Order Derivatives")
```

[image]

Comment: Also worth to be noted: the **splines2** package computes as well the indefinite integral from the leftmost knot.

Comment: Note that if you use the simple truncated power basis the derivatives are very easy to write analytically.  See [this](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg#fig-gen-splinederivs).